# Regex Find Consecutive Letters

Tags: python, regex

how can i find consecutive string "210" in string "21043213213". The string will always begin with '210'.

The issue i am having is that if "210" is in the middle of the string it will still print it. In example below it turned "K" to "L" because it found a 210 in the string. How can i tell regex to find only "210" in the beginning.

Example:

Input:

```
1fzzvk   K 21000345678
1fzzvk   K 34210887632
```

Expected Output:

```
1fzzvk K 21000345678
1fzzvk L 34210887632
```

Code:

```
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    with open(dir+'wupannew.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for f in file:
            if re.search('210', f):
                rflag = re.sub('L', 'K', f)
                fout.write(rflag)
                print(f)
            if not re.search('210', f):
                rflag = re.sub('K', 'L', f)
                fout.write(rflag)
```

Comment: for '210210' should pring 210 two times ?

Comment: @kederrac No it should only print once. The other if statement is "not".

Comment: so only one time ? even here '1121032321000210' ?

Comment: @kederrac No it should always begin with "210". I cannot use the function .startswith() because this "210" is not the first characters in the whole entire line in the file.

Comment: can you explain what is your issue? what is your expected print? which case is fine and which is not?

Comment: Try `re.search(r'\b210',f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
import re

s = "21043213213"

r = re.search('210', s)
if r:
    print(r.group())
```

---

after your edit:

```
import re

s1 = '1fzzvk   K 21000345678'
s2 = '1fzzvk   K 34210887632'


print(re.sub(r'K 210', 'L 210', s1))
print(re.sub(r'K 210', 'L 210', s2))
```

output:

```
1fzzvk   L 21000345678
1fzzvk   K 34210887632
```

Comment: I get an attribute error. if re.search('210', f).group(f):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @iampython2134 because there is not '210' in your string, what do you expect to happen if there is no '210' in the string ?

Comment: Would want it go on to the next line or group of characters.

Comment: @iampython2134 you could use an `if` statement like in my answer

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate it. I will be more detail oriented next itme.If im looping through a file it will still pick up 34210887632. Can i have it picking up if a string is '21000345678' in the file only? Please look at my edited question.